# Computer claims it's connected to wifi, but it's not

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dns

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, 64-bit.

I know close to nothing at all about Linux so please go easy on me.

Connection dropped - possibly because I apparently opened too many tabs at once over my VPN.

Now my wifi isn't connecting at all. I've tried multiple networks, both wireless and ethernet.

However, both the network name & wifi icon are displayed in top right dropdown menu, somehow with varying network strength.

When I click the wifi menu, my network has a tick next to it just like it was connected normally.

It's identified two different wifi networks (so presumably can connect at least sorta?) but won't actually load anything from either of them.

Attempts to fix it myself:

- Pinging 8.8.8.8 gives a 100% packet loss.
- Hashing out "nameserver 127.0.0.53" in resolv.conf and writing "nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4" on the two lines below doesn't work, and resolv.conf has reset if I check directly after I save my changes.
- Tried to reinstall drivers via a mounted ISO but the "Additional Drivers" page of Software & Updates (with the CD-ROM box ticked) says "No additional drivers available".
- Network Manager (GNU 4.8) is blank, and it might not have been before - not sure.
- Would post details from iwconfig and ifconfig but I know there's private data in there and don't trust myself to post the useful stuff without revealing anything.

Attempted lots of solutions from StackExchange, YouTube, etc. (too many to remember) so I may have dug myself deeper.

Comment: Have you managed to download anything from those WiFi connections with any device (eg mobile phone)? Would be nice to know if the WiFi point actually has internet access. The WiFi icon on your screen shows that you’re connected to the wireless access point, but doesn’t say anything about that device’s internet connectivity.

Comment: Which VPN are you using? Some of them are quite disruptive when it comes to network connectivity ...

Comment: The WiFi connections are fine, they've worked with both laptops and mobiles.